# copy column value from `sales_shipment` to `sales_shipment_grid`

Tags: magento2, copydata

I create custom attribute("custom_feild") in `sales_shipment` table and save value.
And also make attribute("custom_feild") in `sales_shipment_grid`. 
How can copy data from custom_feild of `sales_shipment` table into `custom_feild` of `sales_shipment_grid` table ?

Comment: Hi, Can you help me how to add custom_field value  in sales_shipment while  create shipment programmatically

Comment: make file  Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\UpgradeSchema.php

Comment: make this upgrade method 

<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
 public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
     }

Comment: paste these link of code in upgrade method 
$salesShipmentGridTable='sales_shipment_grid';
 $setup->startSetup();
 $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($salesShipmentGridTable),
                'custom_attrbute',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();

Comment: you will find the answer (Y) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Add a column in **sales_shipment_grid** table like you have in **sales_shipment**

Then add a **sales_order_shipment_grid.xml** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_shipment_grid.xml

add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                         
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_shipment_columns">
<column name="custom_feild">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Column Name Goes here</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>                                                    
</columns>                                                   
</listing>
```

then add **di.xml** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                   
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
<arguments>
    <argument name="columns">
        <item name="custom_feild" xsi:type="string">sales_shipment.custom_feild</item>
    </argument>
</arguments>                                                     
</virtualType>                                                        
</config>
```

**custom_feild** is the name of column which you have in **sales_shipment** table and make sure you have same column in **sales_shipment_grid** table as well.

> NOTE : When you post data into sales_shipment table next time then it will also be added into sales_shipment_grid table as then xml will list the column in grid view.

Run below commands after you made these changes

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: not need to overrid the `sales_order_shipment_grid.xml` because am not need to display column on grid.
and in `virtualType` tag this name  `name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Grid"` generate `xmlSchemaDocWalk` error.
I follow the magento module/sales/etc/di.xml there in virtualtype tag name has `name="ShipmentGridAggregator"` . it copy value in `sales_shipment_grid` table.
Thanks

Comment: Ok fine thenm if you don't want to display in shipment grid then you can ignore sales_order_shipment_grid.xml and will the di.xml copied the value in sales_shipment table ?? @HaFizUmer

Comment: yes copy value in grid table. But i use virtualtype name="ShipmentGridAggregator" .
i your solution virtual class name create `xmlSchemaDocWalk` error.